# DB2 SQL to count number of rows with respective to 2 columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have data in DB2 table something like this

| main_id | sub_id | key_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1001 | 1 | 0 |
| 100 | 1001 | 2 | 0 |
| 101 | 1002 | 1 | 0 |
| 102 | 1003 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 1004 | 1 | 1 |
| 103 | 1005 | 2 | 2 |
| 103 | 1006 | 2 | 2 |
| 104 | 1007 | 2 | 0 |
| 105 | 1008 | 2 | 1 |
| 105 | 1009 | 2 | 1 |

Now I am trying to create output something like this where :

```
count1 - main_id count with multiple rows only with key id 1
count2 - main_id count with multiple rows only with key id 2
count3 - main_id count with multiple rows with combo 1 & 2 key id
```

| Type | count_1 | count_2 | count_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 |  | 1 |  |

Overall, I need distinct main_id's count with multiple rows of sub_id and then need to segregate them based on type and key_id's

In the above case :

- 100 - has 2 rows w/ 1001 but key_id's are differnt  -`count_3`
- 102 - has 2 rows w/ 1002 and 1003 but key_id's are from 1 - `count_1`
- 103 - has 2 rows w/ 1005 and 1006 but key_id's are from 2 - `count_2`
- 105 - has 2 rows w/ 1008 and 1009 but key_id's are from 2  -`count_2`

Ignored 101 and 104 as there are no multiple rows for that main_id

```
    WITH main_ids AS (
  SELECT main_id, key_id, type, COUNT(sub_id) sub_id_count
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY main_id, key_id, type
),
grouped AS (
  SELECT type, COUNT(main_id) main_id_count
  FROM main_ids
  WHERE sub_id_count > 1
  GROUP BY type
)
SELECT type,
  SUM(CASE WHEN key_id = 1 THEN sub_id_count END) count_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN key_id = 2 THEN sub_id_count END) count_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub_id_count > 1 THEN sub_id_count END) count_3
FROM main_ids
JOIN grouped ON grouped.type = main_ids.type
GROUP BY type
```

Need help with count_3 condition, is there any way where can get count of main_id having multiple rows with both key_id 1 and 2(in the above case only 100 main_id is satisfying that condition)

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
  T (main_id, sub_id, key_id, type) AS
(
VALUES 
  (100, 1001, 1, 0)
, (100, 1001, 2, 0)
, (101, 1002, 1, 0)
, (102, 1003, 1, 1)
, (102, 1004, 1, 1)
, (103, 1005, 2, 2)
, (103, 1006, 2, 2)
, (104, 1007, 2, 0)
, (105, 1008, 2, 1)
, (105, 1009, 2, 1)
)
, G AS 
(
  SELECT TYPE, KEY_ID, COUNT (DISTINCT MAIN_ID) C
  FROM T
  GROUP BY TYPE, KEY_ID
)
SELECT 
  TYPE
, CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN 1 END AS COUNT_1
, CASE WHEN C2 = 1 THEN 1 END AS COUNT_2
, CASE WHEN C1 > 1 AND C2 > 1 THEN 1 END AS COUNT_3
-- Just for convenience
, C1
, C2
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    M.TYPE
  , COALESCE (G1.C, 0) AS C1  
  , COALESCE (G2.C, 0) AS C2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM G) M
  LEFT JOIN G G1 ON G1.TYPE = M.TYPE AND G1.KEY_ID = 1
  LEFT JOIN G G2 ON G2.TYPE = M.TYPE AND G2.KEY_ID = 2
)
```

| TYPE | COUNT_1 | COUNT_2 | COUNT_3 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |  | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is working as expected for the sample shared , but giving ALL NULL as part of count1 and count2 when executed for data volume which is 1M+ and even for count_3 its giving 1 for all types which is not correct.

Comment: Edit your question with another example of data, when the query returns wrong result and show the desired one. I can't guess about your unknown data...